# What exactly does "printw" do? (Ncurses)

Tags: ncurses

Could someone please tell me what exactly does printw do? I tried looking for information but just could not find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5 seconds on `Google` revealed some nice documentation.

```
printw() class: Print formatted output similar to printf()
```

and

```
6.3.1. printw() and mvprintw

These two functions work much like printf(). mvprintw() can be used to move 
the cursor to a position and then print. If you want to move the cursor first 
and then print using printw() function, use move() first and then use printw() 
though I see no point why one should avoid using mvprintw(), you have the 
flexibility to manipulate.
```

Source - [NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/printw.html)

Answer (score 1):

Type `man printw` (I suppose you are not programming with Windows).